# Creating Excel "spinners" with Python in openpyxl

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am writing an Excel sheet from Python, using openpyxl, and would like to insert "[spinners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinner_(computing))" into the sheet.

I have been so far unable to find anything on this. I am open to using other Python packages as well.

If this cannot be done, is there another way of doing this? I was thinking something along the lines of writing a macro from Python and somehow merge it with the Excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

It seems from [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/467) that openpyxl doesn't support ActiveX controls, and they will be discarded if the workbook is processed by openpyxl.

---

If you have Excel installed, all of the following should be accessible via pywin32.

[Here is a good overview](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-forms-Form-controls-and-ActiveX-controls-on-a-worksheet-15BA7E28-8D7F-42AB-9470-FFB9AB94E7C2) to the different types of controls available to Excel

It seems that there are two types of controls that can be embedded into an Excel worksheet:

- Excel controls (older, backwards compatible to Excel 5)
- ActiveX controls (newer and more customizable)

---

**Excel controls**

The Excel Automation `Worksheet` object has a method called `Spinners`, which itself has a method `Add`. The VBA code looks like this (generated using the Macro Recorder):

```
ActiveSheet.Spinners.Add(816, 36, 92.25, 49.5)
```

I didn't manage to find any documentation on programmatically adding these controls.

---

**ActiveX controls**

These appear to be the standard Microsoft Forms documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692790.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Specifically, the SpinButton control is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251572.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Using the Macro Recorder, I get the following:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.SpinButton.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=633, Top:=47.25, Width:=58.5, Height:= _
    62.25)
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks a lot for the info (+1) :) Just happens that I'm using mac where win32 is not going to work :/

Comment: @denvar I haven't looked at the source of openpyxl, but presumably since Excel .xlsx files are compressed sets of XML files, that is what openpyxl is doing -- decompressing the xlsx file and parsing the XML inside. Perhaps doing the same would be feasible for you, or perhaps it might even be possible to leverage openpyxl's decompression and XML parsing, at least.

Comment: Re: "oh, it's just zipped XML, why not just poke around yourself?" If you are not experienced working with raw Excel files, trying to shoehorn something into them is *highly* nontrivial. The format is nowhere near as simple as most people imagine. That is why there are packages like OpenPyXL, XlsxWriter, and xlrd. (Even if you are an expert, depending on what you want to do, it's still difficult. Why do you think those packages don't have such-and-such features?) Excel automation (as you've suggested) is the far better choice for this kind of thing.

Comment: Re: "what if I'm using a Mac?" Try xlwings, which does its best to work on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: @JohnY thanks for the xlwings reference (+1), looks really awesome. I am trying to figure out if I can programatically add a button, e.g., from Python into a new excel workbook, not sure if this library does that (or if any library does that...).

Comment: @denvar If I understand correctly, every object in xlwings has an `api` property which returns the native object; in the case of a Mac, this returns the AppleScript sheet object. Presumably you could then call `.Spinners.Add` on [that object](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Sheet.api) with the appropriate parameters.